# Can an electromagnet sense magnetic load on it?

Tags: electromagnetism

Say I have an electromagnet, and I put a permanent magnet next to it, the fields repelling. Is there a circuit that can be created that will detect the magnetic load on the electromagnet produced by the permanent magnet's magnetic field in the form of increased or decreased electrical activity within the electromagnet?

Comment: Repelling is a form of pressure, so you might want to look into load cells.

Comment: You could also try monitoring the total magnetic field at some point in front of the electromagnet using a Hall sensor.

Comment: Is detecting movement in the permanent magnet good enough?

Comment: Only if the magnet is moving to produce a changing flux within the electric magnet.